# How to extract month, day, year, hour in Unix Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp, fullcalendar, strtotime

In my database as i insert the date and time converted to timestamp using strtotime, it is like "1444600800" and I also have a time duration for a certain service which is converted to the same process, "1443740700", now I am using https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE, with its' http://fullcalendar.io/, in the calendar events, it is coded like this for an event:

```
  events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 30),
                        backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red 
                        borderColor: "#f56954" //red
                    } ]
```

I coded it like this but don't succeed:

```
events:
    [
    <?php $event_query = mysql_query("select *,TIME_FORMAT   (`appoint_date`, '%H:%i') from appointment INNER JOIN service,user where  appointment.user_id = user.user_id and service.service_id =  appointment.service_id")or die(mysql_error());
          while($event_row = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)){


    ?>
    {
        title  : '<?php echo $event_row['firstname']; ?> ',
        start  : <?php echo $event_row['appoint_date']; ?>,
        end  : <?php echo $event_row['duration']; ?>,
        allDay: false,
        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
        borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
    },
    <?php } ?>
    ]
```

I am thinking of extracting the date, month, hour in timestamp , i can just add the hour value of my timestamp from service duration to a date and time timestamp and code it like the sample. with a formula :

```
`$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
               // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60 secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";`
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
start: new Date(<?=$event_row['appoint_date']?>000)
```

Note that you need to multiply by 1000 (in the above, just add three zeroes) because timestamps in JS are in milliseconds, whereas in PHP they're in seconds.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I suppose you could just add the three zeroes like that... :-)

Comment: how can I extract the time duration and add it to the timestamp? so i can insert its result to the end: ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor has a single-argument version, which accepts milliseconds-since-the-Epoch. A Unix timestamp is usually seconds-since-the-Epoch (yours are, anyway), and so:

```
start : new Date(<?php echo $event_row['appoint_date']; ?> * 1000),
```

...will create the relevant date on the client side (note the `* 1000`).

Comment: I am thinking of adding a time value to the date, is it possible to an hour duration timestamp to the date? i need also to code the end:like this      end  : <?php echo $event_row['duration+appoint_date']; ?>, something like that